# Mongo Template with spring

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I am trying to retrieve something like,

```
select client from Companies where company id=5;
```

with,

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is("5"));
query.fields().include("client");
```

But this is getting nothing. Did I do wrong. Can anyone help me on this or can anyone provide better resources to learn.

Comment: how are you querying the database? mongotemplate? show that code

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow..please maintain where("company id"). maintain the Bean name  (Companies )